# Error al ejecutar procedimiento de almacenado para actualizar datos

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedure

[image: Tabla producto]

[image: Este es el registro que tengo en la tabla]

[image: Este es el error que me aparece al momento que ejecuto el procedimiento de almacenado]

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Actualizar_producto]
@Cod_producto int,
@Nombre Varchar(50),
@Descripcion text,
@Fecha_vencimiento date,
@Valor int,
@Cantidad int AS UPDATE Producto SET Nombre=@Nombre, Descripcion=@Descripcion, Fecha_vencimiento=@Fecha_vencimiento, Valor=@Valor, Cantidad=@Cantidad where Cod_producto= @Cod_producto RETURN 0
```

**He cambiado el formato de la fecha al momento de ejecutar el procedimiento de almacenado por "/" y me sigue saliendo el mismo error**

Comment: Prueba a poner '2001-03-01', puede que sea ese el error

Comment: Tú valor de fecha debe ir entre comillas simples. Ej. '2001-03-01'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En SQL, en general, cuándo escribes fechas, como valores literales dentro de una sentencia, las escribes como constantes de cadena de caracteres, es decir, entre comillas simples.

En SQL Server específicamente, el formato de fecha *universal*, en mi experiencia, es `'aaaammdd'`, sin ningún tipo de separador. Si es una fecha y hora, entonces `'aaaammdd hh:mm:ss'`.

Resumiendo, tu llamada podría ser algo como:

```
exec actualizar_producto 
     @Cod_producto = 1
   , @Nombre = 'aaa'
   , @Descripcion = 'bbb'
   , @Fecha_vencimiento = '20190401'
   , @Valor = 3453
   , @Cantidad = 43;
```

Si quieres utilizar otros formatos de fechas, puedes utilizar el que esté configurado en tu conexión cliente, o bien valerte de la función `convert()`, para ir de manera segura de una cadena de texto a una fecha.